# How to get all names for enum items with same value?

Tags: c#, enums

`Foo` and `Bar` enum members share the same associated value of 180:

```
public enum EnumShareValues
{
    Default = 0,
    Foo = 180,
    Bar = 180,
}
```

This code prints `String representation of 'Bar' is 'Foo'` which is correct, it returns the first occurence of value 180:

```
const EnumShareValues bar = EnumShareValues.Bar;
Debug.WriteLine("String representation of 'Bar' is '{0}'", bar);
```

But is it somehow possible to get both names for enum item with value of 180? 
Something like:

```
// would in this case return "Foo, Bar"
Enum.GetAllNames(typeof(EnumShareValues), EnumShareValues.Bar, ",");
```

**Edit:**
Finally after some testing and fiddling I ended with the following code. Thank you for all your answers!

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetAllNames<T>(T propValue) 
    where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    if (!typeof(T).IsEnum) 
        throw new ArgumentException("T must be an enumerated type");

    var allNames = Enum.GetNames(typeof(T))
        .Where(name => ((T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), name)).Equals(propValue));

    return allNames;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this general-puprose method works ([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nsjAwR)):

i start from enum names and get corresponding values:

```
public static class Util
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetSynonims(this Enum value)
    {
        Type e = value.GetType();   

        return Enum.GetNames(e).Where(n => Enum.Parse(e, n).Equals(value));
    }
}
```

usage:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ",  EnumShareValues.Bar.GetSynonims()));
```

prints:

```
Foo, Bar
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Enum.Parse was needed here. I have accepted the answer of Damnien because he answered sooner.

Comment: @dee, it is up to you. note that `GetSynonims` works with different enums

Comment: I've changed my mind :). But both answers are very helpfull for me.

Answer (score 2):

Your enums need to be unique, if you duplicate the id then you end up with the following stored internally - look for the debug window with the values in the collection. I suggest a small refactor of the code to accommodate. [image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The enum comes with third party library, not possible to refactor it.

Comment: Ouch :)   I see there are other answers that do the job, glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing built in, but you can string a few different methods together easily enough:

```
var allNames =
    Enum.GetNames(typeof (EnumShareValues))
        .Where(name => (EnumShareValues)Enum.Parse(typeof (EnumShareValues), name)
                       == EnumShareValues.Bar);
```

If we were allowed to restrict generic methods to enums, this would be great to wrap up as a generic helper method. You can, of course, do so, but it will produce runtime errors if you try to use it with a non-enum based type.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this helped me!