# Get original unique C# Enum objects when they share an integral value

Tags: c#, .net, enums, custom-attributes, system.reflection

If I have a C# enum where two objects map to the same integral value, is there any possible way to get each unique `Enum` object? Every method I have tried returns only one of the objects - which is likely the first occurrence of the value.

Let's say I have the following enum defined where two objects map to the same integral value for some reason.

```cs
public enum Testing
{
    [Description("This is Value1")]
    [Display(Name = "Value 1")]
    Value1 = 0,

    [Description("This is Value2")]
    [Display(Name = "Value 2")]
    Value2 = 1,

    [Description("This is Value3")]
    [Display(Name = "Value 3")]
    Value3 = 2,

    [Description("This is Value4")]
    [Display(Name = "Value 4")]
    Value4 = 0
}
```

In this case, by some criteria I need `Value1` and `Value4` to both map to the integral value 0. Functionality the two values will result in identical behavior in the application. The reasoning behind why these two options exists is not necessarily relevant, but let's say for example I want it to be extremely clear to the user that Value1 and Value4 are both mapping to 0 even though they are not necessarily the same option.

I then want to dynamically at runtime load the enum objects from the `Testing` type. With enums where two options do not map to the same integral value there are plenty of ways to do this. Using `Enum.GetValues()`, `Enum.GetNames`, using reflection to get a `FieldInfo[]` and then iterating each and calling `FieldInfo.GetValue()`. These all work just fine normally... but when two Enum objects map to the same integral value, usage of any methods which give back the Enum object will return the same object for both `Value1` and `Value4` - likely `Value1`.

However, in this case I have set specific attributes on each of the objects. I want to load the objects in a manner that allows me to utilize those attributes during runtime. Perhaps I want to show each option in a pull-down and want to use the name in the `Display` attribute to give more user-friendly strings, or be able to provide an additional lengthy description in the tooltip of each option.

I have tried the following methods to no avail, they all result in giving back the `Value1` object for `Value4` which inevitably results in accessing the custom attributes for `Value1` and NOT `Value4`.

```cs
foreach (Enum value in Enum.GetValues(type))
{
    // value for Value4 is Value1...
}

foreach (string name in Enum.GetNames(type))
{
    Enum value = (Enum)Enum.Parse(type, name);
    // value for Value4 is Value1...
}

foreach (FieldInfo fieldInfo in type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static))
{
    Enum value = (Enum)fieldInfo.GetValue(null);
    // value for Value4 is Value1...
    // fieldInfo DOES have the custom attributes for Value4 and DOES have the original name Value4
}
```

Is there any possible way to retain the original enum object for `Value4` in C#? I could technically store the `FieldInfo` objects, but I would rather (and need to) store the Enum object. I'm quite surprised that not even iterating the field infos through reflection where I definitely do have the `Value4` field doesn't return that object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all names for enum items with same value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33607904/how-to-get-all-names-for-enum-items-with-same-value)

Comment: It does not. That gets the unique name string object for each but I want the unique Enum object.

Comment: I'm confused. Based on what are you looking it up? If you have the number 0, then obviously you can't know if it was Value1 or Value4. If you have the string "Value4", then your `foreach (FieldInfo fieldInfo` enumeration finds it correctly, does it not?

Comment: It is not possible to distinguish between `(Enum)Testing.Value1` and `(Enum)Testing.Value4`  Both are boxed, and therefore store the type `Testing` in addition to the value `0`.  That's it.  No secret information you could use to tell the difference.

Comment: I do not have the integral value. I am loading each of the Enum objects in that type at runtime. Clearly both objects were defined at compile time. Where did the object for Value4 go? Does it never create an explicit object for Value4?

Comment: You could maybe use a flyweight pattern and do a lookup in a `Dictionary<FieldInfo, Enum>` instead of `fieldInfo.GetValue(null)`, so that the object identity would mean something.... but that won't survive e.g. serialization.

Comment: `Value1` and `Value4` don't exist at runtime, they're just constants which are the same number. There is simply no information there to be able to tell you. You should probably think about making an Enum class, see eg https://stackoverflow.com/a/16507847/14868997

Comment: What you should do is take the numbers `{ 0, 1, 2, 0 }` out of the "value" of each option, and instead let the compiler assign unique values.  The associated numbers can be attached via attributes as you already proposed for other data.

Comment: Any solutions requiring to modify the implementation of the enum is simply not possible. This is in a large software with lots of enums defined in various namespaces and assemblies. 

It seems the best I can do is possibly create my own class which stores the custom attributes, integral value, name etc. of the Enum and use that instead of Enum objects directly.

Comment: @Charlieface Surely [they exist at runtime](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Y7J9ck)?

Comment: @GSerg the OP is asking about disambiguating the enum member used to instantiate a specific instance, when two members map to the same value

Comment: @GSerg No that's just reflection on the metadata. You can do the same thing with constants https://dotnetfiddle.net/79qLy2 ultimately the `int` value is hardcoded into the bytecode wherever it's used. There is simply no way of differentiating between two constant `int`s of the same value, and the same goes for two enum members. See also sharplab for the IL https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQyDMABGgQMIEDeOB1RhyALAQLIAUAlBVTdwG4CGAJwIAPAgF4CAUwB0PVAG4u1AL45VuQpIB2AVwC2Uztl7pxBAAxQlBOWfNqgA===

Comment: See, the thing is that that's not technically true, @Charlieface. You can easily write a Roslyn analyzer that parses the call using the correct enum name, and then write a source generator that does something with it. The problem is that the "something" is a gigantic question mark, because what OP is describing makes no sense. If anything, I'd just create a collection of the values of the `Display` attribute and bind that to his dropdown, then use it to convert to a value when done (or through a converter). But he says he "can't" for some reason? Shrug.

Comment: @Blindy That's source code level. At runtime it just doesn't exist.

Comment: Fun fact, `Testing.Value1 == Testing.Value4`.

Comment: I'm not sure when I said I couldn't use a collection of Display attributes. However, that is definitely not the kind of solution I desire. That would also require multiple collections to track other information, like the Description attributes etc. -> almost as if I need my own object to track all this information, which surprise I already determined is probably my best option In my comment above. It's just not ideal, because extension methods and such that have already been written for Enum objects cannot be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for is not possible. An example program can quickly demonstrate the problem here:

```cs
using System;

public enum ExampleEnum
{
    SomeValue = 1,
    AliasValue = 1
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var x = ExampleEnum.AliasValue;
        Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
    }
}
```

You would naturally expect this program to write 'AliasValue' to the console, but instead you see 'SomeValue'. The reason for this is easy enough to understand - enums are implemented as integers behind the scenes. When going from an integer back to the Enum member, C# will just pick the first member that has the corresponding value. C# only preserves the integer value, and if two enum members have the same value then they should be assumed to have the same behaviour too.

> In this case, by some criteria I need Value1 and Value4 to both map to the integral value 0. Functionality the two values will result in identical behavior in the application. The reasoning behind why these two options exists is not necessarily relevant, but let's say for example I want it to be extremely clear to the user that Value1 and Value4 are both mapping to 0 even though they are not necessarily the same option.

I would suggest you reconsider this approach. If there is no difference in behaviour, then it should not matter if the label gets 'auto-corrected' to the first option. If it *does* matter, then it sounds like there *is* a difference and they should not have the same value.

---

Since there's still some confusion, I'll add more to my example. You aren't converting between integer and enum yourself, but C# *is* doing something like that behind the scenes. It might help you to assume 'Enum' is just syntactic suger for a wrapper around the 'integer' type, and each member is converted into a 'const int' field:

```
public record struct ExampleEnum(int value)
{
    public static readonly ExampleEnum SomeValue = new(1);
    public static readonly ExampleEnum AliasValue = new(1);

    public string ToString() => value switch =>
    {
        1 => "SomeValue",
        _ => value.ToString(),
    };
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var x = ExampleEnum.AliasValue;
        Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
    }
}
```

**This is not **exactly** what happens behind the scenes, but it is a close approximation*

Comment: But I don't want to go back from an integer to the Enum object. I just want the Enum object through reflection. I get that casting and accessing the member directly reroutes to SomeValue. But, the FieldInfo for AliasValue exists... so why does this suddenly reroute to SomeValue when I call GetValue? The field is obviously unqiue.

Comment: @jhdepoiii It's like if you had two constants `const int x = 1; const int y = 1;` there is simply no way to differentiate what that `1` is when used somewhere else.

Comment: And yet I already have access to the original field (x and y) which assigned that value. I just simply cannot bind the field to a unique Enum object.

Comment: I think that's a little crass, but I'll give you that I don't necessarily understand how enums are represented behind the scenes. Never spent much time on understanding that. It seems that the Enum object is essentially a glorified integral value and does not represent the field. So I at least understand now why it is not possible to do what I want using the Enum class.

Comment: @jhdepoiii I've added more to the bottom to help explain. Yes, enums are glorified integer values. You can actually change which integral type is used: `public enum Foo : byte { ... }` creates an enum backed by a byte instead of an int.